# Textbooks on algorithms for the perturbative calculation of High energy physics

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, computational-physics, software, algorithms

For the perturbative calculation of High energy physics, I have known some packages such as FeynArts, FeynCalc, MadGraph, CompHEP, GiNaC, and so on. But I am wondering whether there exists a textbook or monograph which systematically explains the underlying algorithms (but not focus on a specific implementation), both on the symbolic and numerical parts. It is expected that the book should cover the topics such as automatic generation of Feynman diagrams, trace simplification, phase space integrals, multi-loop Feynman integrals, regularization, and so on. Does anyone know one of them?